# digit() in CharacterData00.class java

Tags: java

Can someone help me understand how exactly(logic, in particular the calculation of value variable) in the below method (taken out of Java 7 SDK java.lang.CharacterData00.class) is the digit value determined for a given character. I ended up here trying to understand Long.valueOf(String) method. Are the properties obtained using getProperties specific to java? I didn't find any details online. Any references or comments would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
int digit(int ch, int radix) {
    int value = -1;
    if (radix >= Character.MIN_RADIX && radix <= Character.MAX_RADIX) {
        int val = getProperties(ch);
        int kind = val & 0x1F;
        if (kind == Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER) {
            value = ch + ((val & 0x3E0) >> 5) & 0x1F;
        }
        else if ((val & 0xC00) == 0x00000C00) {
            // Java supradecimal digit
            value = (ch + ((val & 0x3E0) >> 5) & 0x1F) + 10;
        }
    }
    return (value < radix) ? value : -1;
}
```

Comment: You have the source code. Why don't you just check what `getProperties` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make an educated guess that *getProperties* reads the [Unicode categories](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table) for the code point. These will be listed in the [Unicode database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) which changes as Unicode is updated with new code points. Java 7 supports Unicode 6.

It then uses a mask to check if the code point is in the *Nd* category.

I don't really follow the remaining logic but I'd guess the code point values digits are assigned follow a pattern. No doubt you'll find more in [the Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html).